# Lost Laravel admin password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Trying to find way to generate a new password while I don't have a reset-password form.
I already tried to copy/paste encrypted value from another database but it still says:

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a quickest solution. You can change any user password via command line with tinker:

```
php artisan tinker

$u =App\User::find(1)

$u->password=bcrypt('newpassword')

$u->save()
```